# Apple applicationMusicPlayer not playing type "LibrarySong" but does play "Song" type?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-music, apple-musickit

Am using Apple [MediaPlayer framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer) and [AppleMusicAPI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi) to play songs in mobile app.

**API call (with search term parameter)**:

```
https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/{id}/search
```

Successfully returns a [Song](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/song) type object
that is playable with the [MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller)

**API call**:

```
https://api.music.apple.com/v1/me/library/songs
```

Successfully returns a [LibrarySong](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/librarysong) type object
but **will not play** with MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer.

I am playing this way:

```
        self.cloudPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer
        self.cloudPlayer?.setQueue(with: [trackId])
        
       Async.main {
            self.cloudPlayer?.prepareToPlay {error in
                if let error = error {
                    logger.debug("Not Loaded, Prepare to Play Error: \(error)")
                } else {
                    logger.debug("Loaded, start playing")
                    self.cloudPlayer?.play()
                }
           }
        }
```

but keep receiving this error when playing all LibrarySong entries only:

```
Not Loaded, Prepare to Play Error: 
Error Domain=MPMusicPlayerControllerErrorDomain Code=6 "Failed to prepare to play" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to prepare to play}
```

does this player play both types of songs?

is there an additional step to play a LibrarySong?

the Library song id format id is :  "id" : "i.ZOMrKR9tv1xP989"

and the Song format id is: "id" : "1442890811"

Answer (score 1):

For LibrarySongs, I ended up using the catalogId in playParams for playback.

For LibrarySongs that don't have a catalogId only a purchasedId, I made another call to get the catalogId for playback

```
https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/songs?ids=\(purchasedId)
```